# How to add a value at the first empty cell in column?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

In my application, I have a datagridview. For each column, there is a button. If clicked, I take the column index and now want to add a user enterd value at the first (bottom or top doesn't matter) free cell of that column. If there is no empty cell, I want to create one.

I tried looping through all rows, getting the cell values and checking if they are empty.

```
string data = "%VALUE%";
int rowIndex = -1;

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridViewTasks.Rows)
{
    data = (string) row.Cells[columnIndex].Value;
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data))
    {                    
        rowIndex = row.Index;
        break;
    }
    else if (row.Cells[columnIndex].RowIndex == dataGridViewTasks.Rows.Count - 1)
    {
        rowIndex = dataGridViewTasks.Rows.Add();
        break;
    }
}

if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(data) && rowIndex > -1)
{                
    dataGridViewTasks[columnIndex, rowIndex].Value = task.name;
}
```

Problem with this solution is:

If for example row 1 and 2 of column A are filled, a new value in column B is added in row 3. So that is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, it`s should work.
Try it:

```
    private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var columnIndex = 1;
        var dataGrid = new DataGridView();

        var index = GetFirstEmptyCellByColumnIndex(dataGrid, columnIndex);
        dataGrid[columnIndex, index].Value = "new value";

    }

    private int GetFirstEmptyCellByColumnIndex(DataGridView dataGrid, int columnIndex)
    {
        var index = -1;
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty((string)row.Cells[columnIndex].Value))
            {
                index = row.Index;
                break;
            }
        }

        return index != -1
            ? index
            : dataGrid.Rows.Add();
    }
```